# How do I get this div to show again using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made a TODO app and added a counter to keep a count of the items in the list. If the counter hits zero, I've set it to re-show a message 'You currently have no tasks. Use the input field above to start adding.'

```
if(count === 0){
  noTasksText.classList.remove('d-none');
}
```

In the console I print out the div and it doesn't have `d-none` in the class list any more which is what I want, however, in the actual DOM it does.

Here is a full example - https://codepen.io/tomdurkin/pen/LYdpXKJ?editors=1111

I really can't seem to work this out. I can't seem to interact with that div when the counter becomes zero, however I can get console logs etc to show when expected.

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
const mainInput = document.querySelector('#main-input');
const todoContainer = document.querySelector('#todo-container');
const errorText = document.querySelector('#js-error');
const noTasksText = document.querySelector('.js-no-tasks')

let tasks = [];
let count = 0;

// focus input on load
window.onload = () => {
  mainInput.focus();

  const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

  if (storedTasks != null && storedTasks.length > 0) {

    // set count to number of pre-existing items
    count = storedTasks.length

    // hide the 'no tasks' text
    noTasksText.classList.add('d-none');

    // overwrite tasks array with stored tasks
    tasks = storedTasks;

    tasks.forEach(task => {
      // Build the markup
      const markup = `
        <div class="js-single-task single-task border-bottom pt-2 pb-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-center js-single-task-name">
              <h5 class="mb-0" data-title="${task}">${task}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="js-remove-task d-block btn btn-danger">Remove Item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;

      // Append it to the container
      todoContainer.innerHTML += markup;
    });

  } else {
    if (noTasksText.classList.contains('d-none')) {
      noTasksText.classList.remove('d-none');
    }
  }

};

// event listener for 'enter on input' 
mainInput.addEventListener("keydown", e => {

  // if error is showing, hide it!
  if (!errorText.classList.contains('d-none')) {
    errorText.classList.add('d-none');
  }

  if (e.key === "Enter") {

    // Get the value of the input
    let inputValue = mainInput.value;

    if (inputValue) {

      // Build the markup
      const markup = `
        <div class="js-single-task border-bottom pt-2 pb-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-center js-single-task-name">
              <h5 class="mb-0" data-title="${inputValue}">${inputValue}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="js-remove-task d-block btn btn-danger">Remove Item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;

      // hide 'no tasks' text 
      noTasksText.classList.add('d-none');

      // Append it to the container
      todoContainer.innerHTML += markup;

      // Push value to 'tasks' array
      tasks.push(inputValue);

      // Put in localStorage
      textTasks = JSON.stringify(tasks);
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", textTasks);

      // Reset the value of the input field
      mainInput.value = '';

      // add 1 to the count 
      count++

    } else {
      // Some very basic validation
      errorText.classList.remove('d-none');
    }

  }
});

// remove task

todoContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // Find the button in the row that needs removing (bubbling)
  const buttonIsDelete = e.target.classList.contains('js-remove-task');

  if (buttonIsDelete) {

    // Remove the HTML from the screen
    e.target.closest('.js-single-task').remove();

    // Grab the name of the single task
    let taskName = e.target.closest('.js-single-task').querySelector('.js-single-task-name h5').getAttribute('data-title');

    // filter out the selected word
    tasks = tasks.filter(item => item != taskName);

    textTasks = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", textTasks);

    // update counter 
    count--

    // check if counter is zero and re-show 'no tasks' text if true
    if (count === 0) {
      noTasksText.classList.remove('d-none');
      console.log(noTasksText);
    }

  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-10 col-lg-6">
      <div class="card p-3">
        <h2>To dos</h2>
        <p>
          Use this app to keep a list of things you need to do
        </p>
        <input class="form-control" id="main-input" type="text" placeholder="Type your todo and hit enter..." class="w-100" />
        <small id="js-error" class="text-danger d-none">
        Please type a value and press enter
      </small>
        <hr />
        <h4 class="mb-5">Your 'To dos'</h4>
        <div id="todo-container">
          <!-- todos append in here -->
          <div class="js-no-tasks">
            <small class="d-block w-100 text-center mb-3">
            <i>
              You currently have no tasks. Use the input field above to start adding
            </i>
          </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /card -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes. "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: Note that you don't need to check if a class exists before calling `remove`; no errors occur if you call `remove` and the class does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove that check!

Comment: I have the feeling this is due to the fact that `querySelector` returns a reference to the element that is not live. You could try doing `document.querySelector('.js-no-tasks').classList.remove('d-none')` and see if that works. It doesn't seem right though, which is why I'm not answering :).

Comment: While you are playing with the DOM using `innerHTML +=`, you are losing the reference of the variable `noTasksText`.


Simple solution would be to declare the variable inside remove button handler `const noTasksText = document.querySelector(".js-no-tasks");`

Comment: Thanks yes, Someone else put that as an answer so I have marked that as the best/cleanest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon setting `innerHTML` by using `+= innerHTML` the node `noTasksText` is lost, because browser processes the whole new set `innerHTML` and creates new objects. You can either retrieve `noTasksText` again after that, or append nodes using `todoContainer.appendChild`. I forked your pen and solved it with the latter solution.

https://codepen.io/aghosey/pen/wvmGwWd

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution - that variable is getting lost so I just removed that variable and used `document.querySelector('.js-no-tasks')` instead. I have made a few updates to the code and created a function for adding an item too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, it will work (here innerHTML is changing the DOM, so I added an extra function to recalculate elements after DOM is changed due to innerHTML):

```js
var mainInput = document.querySelector("#main-input");
var todoContainer = document.querySelector("#todo-container");
var errorText = document.querySelector("#js-error");
var noTasksText = document.querySelector(".js-no-tasks");

let tasks = [];
let count = 0;

function getAllElements() {
  mainInput = document.querySelector("#main-input");
  todoContainer = document.querySelector("#todo-container");
  errorText = document.querySelector("#js-error");
  noTasksText = document.querySelector(".js-no-tasks");
}
// focus input on load
window.onload = () => {
  mainInput.focus();

  var storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));

  if (storedTasks != null && storedTasks.length > 0) {
    // set count to number of pre-existing items
    count = storedTasks.length;

    // hide the 'no tasks' text
    noTasksText.classList.add("d-none");

    // overwrite tasks array with stored tasks
    tasks = storedTasks;

    tasks.forEach((task) => {
      // Build the markup
      const markup = `
        <div class="js-single-task single-task border-bottom pt-2 pb-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-center js-single-task-name">
              <h5 class="mb-0" data-title="${task}">${task}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="js-remove-task d-block btn btn-danger">Remove Item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;

      // Append it to the container
      todoContainer.innerHTML += markup;
      getAllElements();
    });
  } else {
    if (noTasksText.classList.contains("d-none")) {
      noTasksText.classList.remove("d-none");
    }
  }
};

// event listener for 'enter on input'
mainInput.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  // if error is showing, hide it!
  if (!errorText.classList.contains("d-none")) {
    errorText.classList.add("d-none");
  }

  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    // Get the value of the input
    let inputValue = mainInput.value;

    if (inputValue) {
      // Build the markup
      const markup = `
        <div class="js-single-task border-bottom pt-2 pb-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-center js-single-task-name">
              <h5 class="mb-0" data-title="${inputValue}">${inputValue}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="js-remove-task d-block btn btn-danger">Remove Item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;

      // hide 'no tasks' text
      noTasksText.classList.add("d-none");

      // Append it to the container
      todoContainer.innerHTML += markup;
      getAllElements();

      // Push value to 'tasks' array
      tasks.push(inputValue);

      // Put in localStorage
      textTasks = JSON.stringify(tasks);
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", textTasks);

      // Reset the value of the input field
      mainInput.value = "";

      // add 1 to the count
      count++;
    } else {
      // Some very basic validation
      errorText.classList.remove("d-none");
    }
  }
});

// remove task

todoContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // Find the button in the row that needs removing (bubbling)
  const buttonIsDelete = e.target.classList.contains("js-remove-task");

  if (buttonIsDelete) {
    // Remove the HTML from the screen
    e.target.closest(".js-single-task").remove();

    // Grab the name of the single task
    let taskName = e.target
      .closest(".js-single-task")
      .querySelector(".js-single-task-name h5")
      .getAttribute("data-title");

    // filter out the selected word
    tasks = tasks.filter((item) => item != taskName);

    textTasks = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", textTasks);

    // update counter
    count--;

    // check if counter is zero and re-show 'no tasks' text if true
    if (count === 0) {
      noTasksText.classList.remove("d-none");
      console.log(noTasksText);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-10 col-lg-6">
      <div class="card p-3">
        <h2>To dos</h2>
        <p>
          Use this app to keep a list of things you need to do
        </p>
        <input class="form-control" id="main-input" type="text" placeholder="Type your todo and hit enter..." class="w-100" />
        <small id="js-error" class="text-danger d-none">
        Please type a value and press enter
      </small>
        <hr />
        <h4 class="mb-5">Your 'To dos'</h4>
        <div id="todo-container">
          <!-- todos append in here -->
          <div class="js-no-tasks">
            <small class="d-block w-100 text-center mb-3">
            <i>
              You currently have no tasks. Use the input field above to start adding
            </i>
          </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /card -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```